# How to make this asyncronous function synchronous

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I call the following function:

```
function uploadReturns() {
    var uploads = me.getIssuesFromReturnsList();
    uploadreturnsobjects(uploads); //process the uploads object and send it to an AJAX call

}
```

In `me.getIssuesFromReturnsList` the `uploadList` variable is being returned before the rest of the code executes because it is asynchronous (as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron))

```
me.getIssuesFromReturnsList = function () {
    var uploadList = [];
    $.each(me.returnsList(), function (index, i) {
        var issue = issueRepository.GetDefaultIssue();
        issue.barcode = i.barcode;
        issue.ReturnsAmount(i.amount);

        var uploadItem = {
            barcode: i.barcode,
            amount: i.amount,
            issue: ko.observable(issue)
        };

        uploadList.push(uploadItem);

        issueRepository.GetIssuesOffline(i.barcode, function (issues) {
            if (issues.length > 0) {
                uploadItem.issue(issues[0]);
            }
        });
    });

    return uploadList;
}
```

How can I alter this code so that the calls are no longer asynchronous, and instead waits for all the inner code to execute before returning the `uploadList`?

Comment: Wrap it in a `Promise`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score -1):

using Promises:

```
function forEachChain (array, func, thisArg) {
    const res = [];

    function exec(resolve, i) {
        func.call(thisArg, array[i]).then((e) => {
            res[i] = e;
            if (i < array.length - 1) {
                exec(resolve, i + 1);
            } else {
                resolve(res);
            }
        }, (err) => {
            res[i] = err;
            if (i < array.length - 1) {
                exec(resolve, i + 1);
            } else {
                resolve(res);
            }
        });
    }

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        if (array.length > 0) {
            exec(resolve, 0);
        } else {
            resolve([]);
        }
    });
}
```

now you can call this function passing an array. for each element of that array `func` is called (passed by you) assuming that it returns a `Promise` too.

The asynchronous calls are called one per time (the concurrent version is a bit more complicated).

In case of Errors, the array will contain the relative error at the relative index.

```
forEachChain(myArray, myFuncReturningAPromise, thisArgInsideEachFuncCall).then((arrOfSameSizeOfMyArray) => { 
    // myCallback
}
```